# Computing $\frac{x^2 - (1/x^2)}{3x^2+5x-2}$ given $x-(1/x)=1$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $x-(1/x)=1$, then what is $$\frac{x^2 - (1/x^2)}{3x^2+5x-2}?$$

I am not getting the numerator into $x-\frac{1}{x}$ format. Please help me.

The denominator is $3x^2+5x-3$.

I divided it by $x$ to get $3x+5-(3/x) = 3(x-(1/x))+5$, so it is $8$.

Moving on to the the numerator:

$(x^2-(1/x))(x^2+(1/x))$

$(x^2-x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

$x^4-x^2-2x-1$

divide by $x^2$

$x^2-(1/x^2)-1-(2/x)$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $x\ne0,$

$$\frac{x^6-1}{x^2(3x^2+5x-3)}=\frac{x^3-\dfrac1{x^3}}{3\left (x-\dfrac1x\right)+5}$$

Use
$$x^3-\dfrac1{x^3}=\left(x-\frac1x\right)^3+3\cdot x\cdot\dfrac1x\left(x-\frac1x\right)$$

Comment: $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)^3+3ab(a+b)$

Comment: yes i got it @lab bhattacharjee

Comment: @tarani, $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)^3+3ab(a-b)$$

Comment: thank you @lab bhattacharjee .i was wasting my time a lot with this problem since morning.within 2 minutes i got it right.